# How do I enable the chrome browser to allow local cookies? --enable-file-cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am currently working with cookies on my local machine and for some reason when I try to look at the cookies it says "By default cookies are disabled for local files. You could override this by starting the browser with --enable-file-cookies command line flag". I tried going into my chrome file location, I left clicked under properties and changed the command line flag after the "target" but that didn't work. I'm not sure how I can enable local cookies at this point.

Answer (score 12):

It would seem that the `--enable-file-cookies` flag has been removed for all platforms except android.

You can read more about it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=470482) and [here](https://codereview.chromium.org/1034703003).