# get is undefined for this.$cookie.get for vuejs

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, vue.js, token

i am using this code in router index.js for login route in Vuejs

```
if (this.$cookie.get('token')) {
    next('/dashboard')
}
```

But i am getting get is undefined

Comment: Do you have to include/reference a plugin vue-cookie? Also Check if you have $cookie object, then do get.

Comment: i have include vue-cookie

Comment: how to check $cookie object if it is not there then how to inclue it

Comment: Did you tell your vue to use the plugin VueCookie? Like Vue.use(VueCookie). You can check using if(this.$cookie){ 'do some cookie things here' }else{ 'no cookie here'}

Comment: i have use vue.use(VueCookie)

Comment: I'm not sure why then.. some people have complained about getting undefined check here  https://github.com/alfhen/vue-cookie/issues/13

Comment: $cookis object is not created there ...

Comment: import VueCookie from 'vue-cookie'

Vue.use(VueCookie)
 I have written this

Comment: Vue.cookie = Cookie;
Vue.prototype.$cookie = Cookie; 
in discussion this is written to use before but Cookie is undefined

Answer (score 2):

I just spent quite a bit of time with this. In entry:

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'
Vue.use(VueCookies)
```

Inside a Vue component:

```
  console.log(this.$cookies);
  this.$cookies.set('test1', 'content');
  console.log(this.$cookies.keys());
  console.log(this.$cookies.get('test1'));
```

The `$cookies` object was defined with all the correct functions, but `keys()` was returning an empty array and `get('test1')` was returning `null`.

Turns out, Google Chrome doesn't support cookies for local files. Try using a different browser.

There used to be a command-line flag to allow cookies for local files, but it [seems to be have been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281019/how-do-i-enable-the-chrome-browser-to-allow-local-cookies-enable-file-cookies).